# Adding buttons in Sencha Touch

Tags: sencha-touch

I want to update the toolbar's content of the main view  from a subview (HotelApp.views.hotelDetail)

This is my toolbar from HotelApp.views.mainView

```
    this.topBar = new Ext.Toolbar({
        dock:'top',
                    id:'main_page_topbar',
        title:'H10 Sencha Demo',
                    items:[this.back,
                           {xtype: 'spacer'}
                    ]
    });
```

The toolbar already have a back button. The problem is i can see the shape of a button, but no text either ID. What i'm doing wrong??

I use this code:

```
var toolbar = HotelApp.views.mainView.getDockedItems()[1];

var images = new Ext.Button({
                 text:'Images',
                 id:'images',
                 ui:'drastic'
 })

toolbar.setTitle(record.get('nombre'));
toolbar.add({items: images});
toolbar.doLayout();
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is only that you have to add your button calling

```
toolbar.add(images);
```

instead of

```
toolbar.add({items: images});
```

I even suggest you to don't use 'id' config for your components but 'itemId'.
In this way you can always get your views components by calling

```
myView.getComponent('myComponentItemId');
```

or

```
myView.getDockedComponent('myComponentItemId');
```

for DockedComponents like toolbars.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Theres an typo in myView.getDcokedComponent('myComponentItemId');